# How is js.erb file trigger on client side?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

When you call a `get` request of a rails controller using `jquery $.get()`,  where the corresponding action does not render a json, if you do have a corresponding js.erb file with the action how does it know to run. Does rails secretly send a request back on the client to recompile or initiate the javascript with the corresponding action?

Answer (score 1):

The get request is sent to your controller.  The controller then based on the request format will render the appropriate template for that format, in this case *.js.erb

as an example, an index.js.erb might look something like:

`$("#product_list").html('<%= escape_javascript( render @products ) %>')`

Rails first evaluates the erb <%= %> which will give an output of something like:

`$("#product_list").html('<div>product1</div><div>product2</div>...')`

This output is now returned as a response to the browser and the browser executes the jquery

Comment: oh yeah that makes sense but in the example code I am looking https://github.com/bodrovis/SitepointMiniChat/blob/comments_polling/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb a get request to the index action made in the polling.coffee file which is in the assets folder, but the index action does not specify format.js yet the code still seems to work. does rails automatically rendering the corresponding javascript for a given action?

Comment: When a controller action doesn't specify a format such as in your example, that action will implicitly respond to all formats.

Now since the jQuery request is a js request, rails knows to render the js response.

Some [documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)